# What is the meaning of str[][20]

Tags: c, string, function, void

I just have a function here in C language, Can you please tell me what does str[ ][20] meaning and why do we need it

```c
void printlist(char str[][20], int n) {
  int i;
  printf("\t*******************************\n");
  printf("\tNo.\t\t\tName");
  printf("\n\t*****************************\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("\t%d \t\t\t%s\n", i + 1, str[i]);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When declared as an **argument**, `char str[][20]` is the same as `char (*str)[20]`. Which means that `str` is a pointer to an array of 20 characters. And to make a long story short, it's an array of strings (where each string can be at most 19 characters long, plus a null-terminator).

Comment: The function is receiving a (pointer to) a 2D array, whos outer dimension isn't needed (or used) by the function definition, but is passed as a separate argument. A function never needs (and ignores) the outermost dimension of an array argument, so a 1D array can be passed as say `func(char str[])`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: About what? The string lengths? The array part? The conversion of what seems to be an "empty" Array to a pointer? Please be specific about what you're wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

`char str[][20]`, means that you have an unknown number of char arrays of size 20.

The parameter `n` to the function `printlist` specifies, how many rows there are in the specified array `str`.

**Example:**

```
int main()
{
    char str[][20] = { "Hello", "World" };
    printlist(str, sizeof str / 20); // <-- printlist(str, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: What do you want me to elaborate on?